# Capture groups in MS Word regex

Tags: regex, ms-word

I am trying to remove the new line prior to "n=", replace with a space and contain the captured number in (), all these in MS Word's advanced find+replace, using wildcards.

Currently:

```
some preceeding text
n=1,233,023
```

Desired result:

```
some preceding text (1,233,023)
```

I've been struggling with ^13n=(*{1,})
and replace with " (\1)" (without the quotes)
but it can't even match it.
Any help please , appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MS Word does have weird ways in regular expressions. The following steps were succesfull for me (mine is in Dutch so please forgive any small translations errors):

- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open *Search And Replace*.
- Tick *More* and tick *Use Wildcards*

Now with this done we can search for:

```
^13(n=[0-9,]{1,})
```

- `^13` - Match newline.
- `(` - Open capture group 1.

  - `n=` - Match "n=" literally.
  - `[,0-9]{1,}` - Match a digit or commas at least 1 time.
- `)` - Close capture group 1.

Replace by:

```
^s\1
```

- `^s\1` - A space followed by capture group 1.

---

As mentioned I would consider the type of regular expressions Word is offering dodgy. [Here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/PowerUser_MSOffice.html) you can read a bit more about it's flaws too. I couldn't create capture groups within a capture group neither was I able to create optional blocks of three consecutive digits and commas. Fortunately in your own attempt just knowing a newline followed by literally `n=` seemed enough.

Second to last note; because I'm Dutch my local parameter seperator is the semi-colon. This also reflects in this search and replace function its occurrence indicators meaning I used: `^13(n=[,0-9]{1;})`

And one last note, another pattern I found worked for me was `^13(n=*^13)`, but since we had zero control of the pattern between `n=` and the paragraph end I would stick with my initial thought. The reason why the use of the `*` worked here is because we used it as an actual frequence of any characters between `n=` and `^13`.

---

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The wildcard search term should be

```
(^13)([a-z])(=)([,0-9]{1,})
```

and the replacement is

```
(\4)
```

Note the first character above is a space.